# How to sort php array if your left place in array is for keys and right for values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, numeric, associative

I had problem with `array_push` so I needed to make numeric array instead of associative. But, as I was doing it, I always pushed 2 values:

1. first was the key to search (ID of object in table)
2. second was some value that was given to object with ID.

So if we would have, let's say, `4` objects with ID's: `1,2,3,4` and we would have given them some values: `20, 50, 40, 30` (going from the lowest ID), my array looks like:

```
1, 20, 2, 50, 3, 40, 4, 30.
```

How can I sort my array from the highest value? The result should be array which looks like:

```
2, 50, 3, 40, 4, 30, 1, 20.
```

Comment: Maybe you could sort it before making it numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP support nested (multi-dimensional) arrays

```
$array = [
    [1, 20],
    [2, 50],
    [3, 40],
    [4, 30]
];
```

Now you can easly sort it

```
usort(
    $array,
    function ($left, $right) { return $right[1] - $left[1]; }
);
var_dump($array);
```

Depending on what this ID and value is, you may consider creating a class instead, especially when there exists other values associated with this ID.

Update: Oh, and because you mentioned

> first was the key to search (ID of object in **table**) and second was some value that was given to object with ID.

When you are talking about database tables, let the database sort for you ;)

```
ORDER BY `valueColumn` DESC
```